# Excel Macro for filtering

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, autofilter

I have a excel table. I want to copy one of the filed, go at table heading in the same column and appliy filter by pasting what was copied.
I have recorded a macro which look as below.

Every time I run my macro, it applies filter to "EVER ELECTRONICS PRIVATE LIMITED" the cell which i used while recording the macro.
I want this to change wheremy active cell is.
Request help.

```
Sub Filter()
'
' Filter Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F
'
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$81").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "=*EVER ELECTRONICS PRIVATE LIMITED*", Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean something like

```
Sub Filter()
    With Selection
        .Copy
        .End(xlUp).Select
    End with

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z81").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*" & ActiveCell.Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

But note that this filter is fixed to the range `Range("A1:Z81")` and if you add data it does not dynamically extend to the data. Therefore you would need to determine the last used row `LastRow` and use it to make your range dynamic.

```
Sub Filter()
    With Selection
        .Copy
        .End(xlUp).Select
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:Z" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*" & ActiveCell.Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for revert. Somehow, the code is not solving my problem. The filter is not applied.

Comment: @sagardbhangale Well then you need to edit your question and give a [mcve] with proper example data and explanation of what you expect. Screenshots might additionally help too.